# Safari document.write() alternative

Tags: javascript

I am creating a new window in javascript and writing its contents using `document.write()`:

```
var windowContent = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
windowContent += '<html>'
windowContent += '<head><title></title></head>';
windowContent += '<body>'
windowContent += '<img src="' + dataUrl + '" width="670px" style=">';
windowContent += '</body>';
windowContent += '</html>';
var printWin = window.open('','newWindow','width=100,height=100');
printWin.document.open();
printWin.document.write(windowContent);
printWin.document.close();
printWin.focus();
printWin.print();
setTimeout(function() {
  printWin.close();
}, 100);
```

In most browsers this works fine, but in Safari 6.0.2, the line `printWin.document.write(windowContent);` will occasionally crash the browser, and other times do nothing, resulting in a blank window.

Is there any alternative to `document.write();` that I should be using instead? From googling, the general advice seems to be to use `document.body.appendChild();`, but the document doesn't have any content to begin with to append to.

Comment: Pretty sure the window have a body element when it is loaded: `printWin.onload=function() { console.log(document.body); }`

Comment: You can try removing the `document.open()` statement since the document is likely already open.

Comment: @NULL - I get the error "An attempt was made to access a Node in a context where it does not exist." when using document.body.appendChild();

Comment: @RobG - that made no difference.

Comment: One way is to make an empty html page on the same domain and open it and inject it with your code.

Comment: What is the value of `dataURL`? And you have an unclosed double quote after the style attribute.

Comment: dataURL comes from a canvas using `canvas.toDataURL();`

Comment: Oh, a valid HTML document only needs a set of title tags and a single set of block element tags. Tags for the mandatory HTML, head and body elements are optional.